# REST API Endpoint naming for specific sub-categories of data

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, endpoint

Say I have an API that (along with other entities) deals with tasks. My endpoints would look something like

```
GET /api/tasks //List all tasks
POST /api/tasks //Create a new task

GET /api/task/1 //Fetch a single task
PUT /api/task/1 //Update a single Tasks

GET /api/task/1/comments //Get the comments of task 1
```

I also need a few subsets of Task data which has an entirely different formats:

- `user-tasks`, tasks for a user but shaped according to schedule.
- `sync-data`, all tasks that need to be sent to an external system with special references

I can see the user data could exist off the user hierarchy such as

```
GET /api/user/1/tasks //tasks for this user with dedicated
```

But what of `sync-data`? Should this fall under the `tasks` heirarchy or under the system it's intended for such as

```
GET /api/ExternalSystemA/tasks //tasks for synchronization
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your URI.  Any spellings that are consistent with the production rules in [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) are fine.

[Relative resolution](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.2) provides a standardized mechanism for computing a new URI from a context and a relative reference.  Designing your hierarchy so that you can take advantage of that is, in some cases, a really good idea.

Otherwise, it is a lot like choosing a variable name - the machine doesn't care, so you just want to choose spellings that are satisfactory for other human beings; in other words, making sure that you are consistent with local conventions.